# Problem with new_row = dict.fromkeys(df, 0) statement

Tags: python, pandas

[image: 2nd name should be under name category]

Here is the code snippet:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
new_row = dict.fromkeys(df, 0)    
new_row[df.columns[0]] = filename
new_row[df.columns[326]] = "Scanware"
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

It is somehow creating a separate column to store the new filename. Same for the column 326.
2ndly I want to know how do I remove the index numbers from csv file? on the left side, more like remove such column from csv.

UPDATE:
The problem was solved by passing index = False parameter to df.to_csv function.

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why append the new DataFrame, you can just assign to the original DF columns:

```
df[df.columns[0]] = filename
df[df.columns[326]] = "Scanware"
```

And while exporting the DataFrame to CSV you can add `index=False` argument to the `.to_csv()`